# CPLEX, replace variable with a constant

Tags: variables, replace, constants, cplex

I already have a CPLEX model with variables `x[0], x[1],...,x[n-1]`. In order to create heuristics, I need to insert constants instead of all but one variable.
Say, I will keep `x[0]` and instead of `x[i]` I will insert constants `a[i] (i=1,...,n-1)`.

One way to do this is to create a new model where variables will be replaced by constants manually. The model is big and I would need go through entire code to do this.

Is there another way?

What if I insert additional constraints: `x[i]==a[i] (i=1,...,n-1)` into the model? Will `x[i]` be converted to constants at the very beginning or the model with *n* variables (`x[i], i=0,...,n-1`)  will be solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can set Upper bound and lower bound on any decision variable to make it a constant.

For instance, with the [zoo example](https://medium.com/p/66940178db6) , in OPL you can write

```
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
float costBus50=700;
 
dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;
dvar int+ nbBus50;
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30+nbBus50*costBus50;
 
subject to
{
 ctKids:40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30+nbBus50*50>=nbKids;
 
 
}

execute
{
  writeln(nbBus30," ",nbBus40," ",nbBus50, " buses");
}

main
{
  thisOplModel.generate();
  
  cplex.solve();
  thisOplModel.postProcess();
  thisOplModel.nbBus50.UB=2;
  thisOplModel.nbBus50.LB=2;
  cplex.solve();
  thisOplModel.postProcess();
}
```

that gives

```
2 6 0 buses
0 5 2 buses
```

Comment: Here is the issue the performance. Will variable "nbBus50" immediately be replaced by constant 2 in every place, or CPLEX will consider "nbBus50" as variable, and during calculations will get "nbBus50=2"?

Comment: The CPLEX preprocessor is very good at this kind of thing. Setting a variable's value using this method should have negligble performance impact